# Error when comparing iterators c++

Tags: c++, iterator

I have the following code :

```
    list<string>::iterator i = files.begin();
    list<string>::iterator j = files.begin();
    walk(argv[1],files);
    for(i=files.begin();i!=files.end();i++) {
        j = i;
        std::advance(i,numberOfCores-2);
        for (j;j<=i;j++){
            cout<<*j<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Here, i want to through 'n' elements in a list in order to launch worker threads. when i'm trying to compile this code, i get the following error: 
*C:\Users\User\Desktop\Eset\map_files.cpp|42|error: no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator >}' and 'std::__cxx11::list >::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator >}')|*

Do you have any idea how can I compare those iterators ?

Comment: Use `!=`, list iterators are not random access iterators so there is no `<=`.

Comment: I can not use != because it will pass through 'i', and i do not want that. Maybe you know another way to do this ?

Comment: Note that `std::advance(i,whatever)` can walk off the end of the sequence, producing undefined behavior.

Comment: Only random access iterators define less/greater than (or equal to) operators.

Comment: Then you increment it checking that `i` is not passed yet.

Comment: What is the goal here? You say "launch worker threads", but that isn't enough to determine what the requirements are here. How many worker threads will there be? Are there specific requirements as to which worker threads get which elements? Does the order of processing the elements matter?